# Port forwarding mechanism

Tags: wireless-router, port-forwarding, xbox360

I have a question about port forwarding. For 'Xbox Live', Microsoft [writes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/open-these-network-ports-for-xbox-one-94d5f68a-387c-1982-7163-6e12a4d9e981) "Xbox Live requires the following ports to be open on your router:

Port 88 (UDP)

Port 3074 (UDP and TCP)"

Et cetera, et cetera. Now my Asus router (RT-AC87U) is a bit more sophisticated than that. Here's an image of my router settings:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO4P2.png)

If you can't see the picture: my router provides columns for External port, Internal port, Source IP and Internal IP. At this moment, I have filled out only the External port column and the internal IP column, but I am not sure whether this is the correct way.

Can someone please tell me?

Comment: You missed out the router model from your question. Please [edit] and add it.

Comment: Apologies. It’s an Asus RT-AC87U

Comment: I own an RT-AC87U but any reasonably modern Asus router is configured in the same way. Your configuration looks correct. The internal port is not filled in so it will be the same as the external port. The source IP is not filled in so it allows access from any outside IP address. If 192.168.1.10 is your internal address, this should work as expected.

Comment: Detailed instructions for XBox Live at https://portforward.com/asus/rt-ac87u/